# Emojis on Facebook Messenger for Android are gone

Tags: facebook-messenger

On Facebook Messenger, I'm used to be able to choose between emoji/sticker/GIF when I press the little smile next to where you enter the messages on iOS. But on my Android phone, there are only stickers and no selection field where I could choose GIF or emoji.

How can I select an emoji or a gif on Android?

If it's relevant, the device is Sony Xperia Z3 Compact running on Android 8.1 Oreo.

Comment: This messenger update pisses me off so much. I am used to pick emojis via this smiley icon and after the update I always end up tapping the smiley again and again, and then have to go back and change my keyboard to pick OS emojis. This is so .. urghh.